# Pimcore install page coming blank

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, nginx, pimcore

I am installing Pimcore 5 using Nginx 1.12.1, MYSQL 5.6, Redis 3.2.4, PHP 7.0, PHP 7.0 FPM with user set nginx and started at 127.0.0.1:9000 on Amazon Linux AMI
My virtual host setting is as

```
#
# A virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#

upstream php-pimcore5 {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    root   /var/www/html/web;
    server_name   pimcoretest.local
    index  index.php index.html;
    #try_files $uri $uri/ /app.php?$args;
    access_log  /var/log/access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/error.log error;

    rewrite ^/cache-buster-(?:\d+)/(.*) /$1 last;

    location ~* /var/assets/*\.php(/|$) {
        return 404;
    }

    location ~* (?:\.(?:bak|conf(ig)?|dist|fla|in[ci]|log|psd|sh|sql|sw[op])|~)$ {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* .*/(image|video)-thumb__\d+__.* {
        try_files /var/tmp/$1-thumbnails$request_uri /app.php;
     #   expires 2w;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location ~* (.+?)\.((?:css|js)(?:\.map)?|jpe?g|gif|png|svgz?|eps|exe|gz|zip|mp\d|ogg|ogv|webm|pdf|docx?|xlsx?|pptx?)$ {
        try_files /var/assets$uri $uri =404;
     #   expires 2w;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    if (-f $document_root/install.php) {
        rewrite ^/install(/?.*) /install.php$1 last;
    }

    location / {
      error_page 404 /meta/404;
      add_header "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=edge";
      try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
      fastcgi_pass php-pimcore5;
    }

    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        send_timeout 1800;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 1800;
    # regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
        try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
        include fastcgi.conf;
        # Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
        # see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
        set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

        # Activate these, if using Symlinks and opcache
        # fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        # fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;

       # fastcgi_pass php-pimcore5;
        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        # http://domain.tld/app.php/some-path
        # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
        internal;
    }

    # PHP-FPM Status and Ping
    location /fpm- {
        access_log off;
        include fastcgi_params;
        location /fpm-status {
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            # add additional IP's or Ranges
            deny all;
        #    fastcgi_pass php-pimcore5;
        }
        location /fpm-ping {
         #   fastcgi_pass php-pimcore5;
        }
    }

    location /nginx-status {
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        stub_status;
    }



}
```

.htaccess in project is as

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex app.php

# By default, Apache does not evaluate symbolic links if you did not enable this
# feature in your server configuration. Uncomment the following line if you
# install assets as symlinks or if you experience problems related to symlinks
# when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets.
# Options FollowSymlinks

# Disabling MultiViews prevents unwanted negotiation, e.g. "/app" should not resolve
# to the front controller "/app.php" but be rewritten to "/app.php/app".
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options +MultiViews
</IfModule>

# mime types
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
AddType image/jpeg .pjpeg

Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

# Use UTF-8 encoding for anything served text/plain or text/html
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine On

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(jpe?g|png)$">
        Header always unset X-Content-Type-Options
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
# If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
# project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
# resolution of the app.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
# work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
# fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
# the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

# Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
# (with and without `/app.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
# rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
# endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
# redirect -> request -> ...).
# So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
# to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
# environment variable, you have 2 choices:
# - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
# - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
#   following RewriteCond (best solution)
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^app\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

<IfModule mod_status.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(fpm|server)-(info|status|ping)
    RewriteRule . - [L]
</IfModule>

# restrict access to dotfiles
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule /\.|^\.(?!well-known/) - [F,L]

# ASSETS: check if request method is GET (because of WebDAV) and if the requested file (asset) exists on the filesystem, if both match, deliver the asset directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(GET|HEAD)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/var/assets%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /var/assets%{REQUEST_URI} [PT,L]

# Thumbnails
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/(image|video)-thumb__[\d]+__.*
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/var/tmp/%1-thumbnails%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /var/tmp/%1-thumbnails%{REQUEST_URI} [PT,L]

# cache-buster rule for scripts & stylesheets embedded using view helpers
RewriteRule ^cache-buster\-[\d]+/(.*) $1 [PT,L]

# rewrite /install to install.php if file exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/install.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/install\.php
RewriteRule  ^install /install.php [L]

# If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
# We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]




##########################################
### OPTIONAL PERFORMANCE OPTIMIZATIONS ###
##########################################

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    # Force compression for mangled headers.
    # http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/12/pushing-beyond-gzipping
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
            RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>

    # Compress all output labeled with one of the following MIME-types
    # (for Apache versions below 2.3.7, you don't need to enable `mod_filter`
    #  and can remove the `<IfModule mod_filter.c>` and `</IfModule>` lines
    #  as `AddOutputFilterByType` is still in the core directives).
    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml application/javascript application/json \
            application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf application/rss+xml \
            application/x-web-app-manifest+json application/xhtml+xml \
            application/xml font/opentype image/svg+xml image/x-icon \
            text/css text/html text/plain text/x-component text/xml text/javascript
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 week"

    # specific overrides
    #ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>

<IfModule pagespeed_module>
    # pimcore mod_pagespeed integration
    # pimcore automatically disables mod_pagespeed in the following situations: debug-mode on, /admin, preview, editmode, ...
    # if you want to disable pagespeed for specific actions in pimcore you can use $this->disableBrowserCache() in your action
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(mod_)?pagespeed_(statistics|message|console|beacon|admin|global_admin)
    RewriteRule . - [L]

    ModPagespeed Off
    AddOutputFilterByType MOD_PAGESPEED_OUTPUT_FILTER text/html
    ModPagespeedModifyCachingHeaders off
    ModPagespeedRewriteLevel PassThrough
    # low risk filters
    ModPagespeedEnableFilters remove_comments,recompress_images
    # low and moderate filters, recommended filters, but can cause problems
    ModPagespeedEnableFilters lazyload_images,extend_cache_images,inline_preview_images,sprite_images
    ModPagespeedEnableFilters combine_css,rewrite_css,move_css_to_head,flatten_css_imports,extend_cache_css,prioritize_critical_css
    ModPagespeedEnableFilters extend_cache_scripts,combine_javascript,canonicalize_javascript_libraries,rewrite_javascript
    # high risk
    #ModPagespeedEnableFilters defer_javascript,local_storage_cache
</IfModule>
```

Document Root is `/var/www/html/web`

I have added following command in app.php as

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

to enable all errors in PHP. Also add these commands in install.php. 
Ensured that project has 0775 permission to user nginx.
There is folder prod present in /var/www/html/var/cache

Now as I am hitting http://pimcoretest.local it get redirected to http://pimcoretest.local/install with no errors in error log and **completely blank**. 
As I inspect in browser it shows 301 redirection and 200 for /install

I have no clue what is problem and how should I troubleshoot it. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Correct configuration:

https://www.pimcore.org/docs/5.0.0/Installation_and_Upgrade/System_Setup_and_Hosting/Nginx_Configuration.html

Check lines 72:

## Use this location when the installer has to be run

## location ~ /(app|install).php(/|$) {

p.s. If you use nginx you can remove .htaccess

Comment: That is not valid anymore since this commit, so I gues that's not the problem: https://github.com/pimcore/pimcore/commit/792a7354fb09ea7c18a9a76d56383ff689d62099

Answer (score 0):

Looking into PHP-FPM log should show you what is wrong:
/var/log/php7.0-fpm.log (on Ubuntu and Debian at least)